# How get device id with firebase messaging

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging, .net-6.0, .net-maui

FirebaseInstanceId was previously used, but is now deprecated.

My work environment is

Net 6.0
Net MAUI
In order to send you a message (push notification) with the Google Firebase service, you must first obtain the Device ID (FCM)

If I see the official documentation it would be like this:

```
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Currently I tried with this package:

https://github.com/Firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet
But there is no such method, and it seems to be used for server side tasks and not client side

With that idea I looked at this package, but I don't see anything similar:
[Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1)

With xamarin this was used:
[Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging)

Comment: The Google link has samples for Java or Kotlin, not Xamarin. Read some samples for your .NET package here and adapt them to your code: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/main/samples/com.google.firebase

Comment: I've had success with the Shiny package. It provides a wrapper around Firebase. You can find more information here - https://shinylib.net/. Their 3.0 library is in alpha, but seems stable.